# Apache url replacement for jquery get / post request

Tags: jquery, apache, http, cross-domain, url-rewriting

I have a web app I'm working on.I use jquery to call a rest api on a remote server.For me to be able to view any code cahnges I need to deploy it on a remote server thus incresing my dev time a lot.The reason I can't run it locally is the cross-doamin security restriction on ajax requests.I thought a solution for this might be to run the app on a local http server and rewriting the url to point to the remote server.Has anybody had to do something similar? Any other approaches?

Thanks

Comment: use the `hosts` file to point the ip address else where ... on "system32/drivers/etc/hosts" you may have examples there :)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't run it locally is the cross-doamin security restriction on ajax requests

rather than try to proxy one of the requests to a different URL (@Val: you need 2 URLs on the same vhost to avoid the problem - changing the hosts file will affect all requests) is there a reason you don't serve up the html page and javascript where the ajax request is inititated from from the same machine as that which handles the ajax?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have a html doc doing all my ajax request,the rest api lies on the same machine I deploy to.So all's good when it's on the same machine.I would like to dev locally and I wan't the ajax requests to fire on the remote machine